# $J^*(A) = J^*(\overline{A})$ for any $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

As I mentioned in Note 1 below, I'm reformulating a proof given by Professor Nelson (Berkley, Math 105). I'd like to confirm that my version is correct (I made a substantive change to one part), and any feedback on proof writing style or other constructive criticism would be much appreciated!

**Lemma.** $J^*(A) = J^*(\overline{A})$ for any $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, where $J^*$ is the Outer Jordan Content and $\overline{A}$
is the closure of A. In particular, $J^*(A):=\inf\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^N
|B_k|\colon N < \infty,\ A\subset \bigcup_{k=1}^N B_k,\ B_k\text{ open
boxes}\right\}$.

**Proof**. Since $\overline{A} \supset A$, any finite covering of $\overline{A}$ covers $A$. So $J^*(\overline{A}) \ge J^*(A)$.

It remains to show that $J^*(\overline{A}) \le J^*(A)$. Let
$$ B := \bigcup_{k=1}^N B_k $$
be any finite covering of $A$ by open boxes. Then
$$ \overline{B} := \bigcup_{k=1}^N \overline{B_k} \supset \overline{A}, \tag{1}$$

where for each $k = 1, \ldots, N$ we have
$$ \overline{B_k} = [a_1, b_1] \times\ldots \times [a_n, b_n]. $$

Now we define a finite open covering of $\overline{A}$ which also contains $\overline{B}$:
$$ B' := \bigcup_{k=1}^N B'_k \supset \overline{B}, \tag{2}$$

where for each $k = 1, \ldots, N$
\begin{align}
B'_k &= \left(a_1 - \frac {\epsilon (b_1-a_1)}{2}, b_1 + \frac {\epsilon (b_1-a_1)}{2}\right) \\
&\times \ldots \\
&\times \left(a_n - \frac {\epsilon (b_n-a_n)}{2}, b_n + \frac {\epsilon (b_n-a_n)}{2}\right)
\end{align}

Then $B' \supset \overline{B} \supset \overline{A}$ and for each $k = 1, \ldots N, $

$$ |B'_k| = (\epsilon + 1)^n |B_k|. \tag{3}$$

It follows from (1), (2), and (3) that
\begin{align}
J^*(\overline{A}) &\le |\overline{B}| \\
&\le |B'| \\
&= (\epsilon+1)^n |B|
\end{align}

Since $B$ was an arbitrary finite covering of A, we deduce
$$ J^*(\overline{A}) \le (1+\epsilon)^n J^*(A) $$

And since $\epsilon >0$ was arbitrary, we finally obtain $ J^*(\overline{A}) \le J^*(A). $ $\square$

Note 1: this proof closely mirrors the proof given by Professor Nelson (Math 105, Analysis 2) for homework 10.3(b), but I formulated $B'$ differently, elaborated in some areas to improve my own understanding, and generally used my own language. See course link [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ebrent/105.html).

Note 2: this problem is referred to in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712551/outer-jordan-content-of-closure-is-equal-to-lebesgue-measure-is-this-false), but no formal proof is given.

Comment: What’s the question?

Comment: Sorry I'll specify in the post -- I'm asking if the proof is correct / any feedback on my proof writing style, etc.

Comment: Your idea for the proof is good.  It is a good idea to elaborate some areas to improve your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering the lemma with a slightly tweaked version of the original (the set of inequalities below (3) are tweaked for clarity).

#### Proof

Since $\overline{A} \supset A$, any finite covering of $\overline{A}$ covers $A$. So $J^*(\overline{A}) \ge J^*(A)$.

It remains to show that $J^*(\overline{A}) \le J^*(A)$. Let
$$ B := \bigcup_{k=1}^N B_k $$
be any finite covering of $A$ by open boxes. Then
$$ \overline{B} := \bigcup_{k=1}^N \overline{B_k} \supset \overline{A}, \tag{1}$$

where for each $k = 1, \ldots, N$ we have
$$ \overline{B_k} = [a_1, b_1] \times\ldots \times [a_n, b_n]. $$

Now we define a finite open covering of $\overline{A}$ which also contains $\overline{B}$:
$$ B' := \bigcup_{k=1}^N B'_k \supset \overline{B}, \tag{2}$$

where for each $k = 1, \ldots, N$
\begin{align}
B'_k &= \left(a_1 - \frac {\epsilon (b_1-a_1)}{2}, b_1 + \frac {\epsilon (b_1-a_1)}{2}\right) \\
&\times \ldots \\
&\times \left(a_n - \frac {\epsilon (b_n-a_n)}{2}, b_n + \frac {\epsilon (b_n-a_n)}{2}\right)
\end{align}

Then $B' \supset \overline{B} \supset \overline{A}$ and for each $k = 1, \ldots N, $

$$ |B'_k| = (\epsilon + 1)^n |B_k|. \tag{3}$$

It follows from (1), (2), and (3) that
\begin{align}
J^*(\overline{A}) &\le \sum_{k=1}^N |B_k'| \\
&= (\epsilon+1)^n \sum_{k=1}^N |B_k|
\end{align}

Since $B$ was an arbitrary finite covering of A, we deduce
$$ J^*(\overline{A}) \le (1+\epsilon)^n J^*(A) $$

And since $\epsilon >0$ was arbitrary, we finally obtain $ J^*(\overline{A}) \le J^*(A). $ $\square$

Note: I again want to give proper attribution to Professor Brent Nelson -- this is a reformulation of his proof, as I mentioned in the original post.